# Best way of grouping and sorting in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have huge data coming from server. I want to sort them and group them. I tried some code and it's working fine. I just want to know is there any better way to optimise the code, which helps in better efficiency.

```
val products = ABC()
products?.sortedBy { it.category }?.groupBy { it.category }
```

**Abc**

```
data class Abc(
    val category: String? = null,
    val categoryId: String? = null,
    ...// more property
)
```

Do you know any better approach?

Comment: Do you actually have a performance issue, or are you optimising prematurely?

Comment: yes it little bit slow

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want the keys of the map (the group keys) to be sorted, right? How about using a sorted map `products.groupByTo(TreeMap()) { it.category }`?

Comment: yes I need to sorted and group by keys. I'll try your code and get back to you.

Comment: @Sweeper it works. thanks a million. Can you explain me what is `TreeMap()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By taking advantage of the fact that you are trying to sort the grouping keys, you can group by and sort at the same time by using a sorted map such as [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Specify the map that you want `groupBy` to use by using `groupByTo`.

```
val map = products.groupByTo(TreeMap()) { it.category }
```

As `groupByTo` creates groups and puts the categories into the map, the keys will automatically be used to build a [Red Black Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) (which is what a `TreeMap` is under the hood). Traversing `map.keys` will get you the keys in sorted order.